# Is it possible to style an XYPlot to look like this?

Tags: androidplot

I'm searching for a XY plot/diagram that give me the ability to make sp lines/curved lines and where I can set the maximum limit of either X or Y values.

I want to make a XY diagram that in the end should look like this visually:
Is it possible with androidplot?[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're wanting to constrain the visible graph area to specific min/max values on both the x and y axis.

In Androidplot 1.0 or later, this code will set your display boundaries on each axis to the range of -1 to 1.

```
plot.setDomainBoundaries(-1, 1, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
plot.setRangeBoundaries(-1, 1, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
```

As far as the more general question of whether or not it's possible to style a plot to look like that picture - definitely; you should be able to make a plot that's virtually identical.